# Am I using ember-cli-bootstrap-sass wrong?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, ember-cli

I have a new ember-cli 0.2.0 app and I am trying to put bootstrap. The steps I followed are:
1) Install this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-bootstrap-sass 2) installed broccoli-sass
3) Put `@import "bootstrap";` in my app.scss file.

I am getting the error: `file to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap` . Should I use bower to download @bootstrap? If yes, what is the purpose of this package?

Comment: I dont think installing broccoli-sass is necessary. This addon should install sass on its own. Check your bower components folder if it contains bootstrap.

Comment: No there isn't a folder with bootstrap inside bower components.

Comment: the bower-installing bootstrap should solve the issue

Comment: Ok so in my steps I also need to install bootstrap as well with bower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
bower install bootstrap-sass
```

and once you have bootstrap-sass in the bower_components directory, include it in your app.scss using:

```
@import "../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

rather than

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: why is https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-bootstrap-sass so wrong? I'm on this too. It seems so simple I don't know why this doc would be wrong.